# Mysql select from more then 2 ranks

Tags: php, mysql

So my problem is that i want select rank 1 and 2,

```
$getCredits = mysql_query("SELECT `look`,`username`,`activity_points` FROM `users` WHERE `rank` = '0'  ORDER BY `activity_points` DESC LIMIT 10");
```

Comment: Use 

`$getCredits = mysql_query("SELECT look,username,activity_points FROM users WHERE rank = '1' OR  rank = '2' ORDER BY activity_points DESC LIMIT 10");`

Comment: Many ways to do this. If you have only positive ranks, you can do `WHERE rank <= 2` or you can do `WHERE rank IN (1, 2)`, `WHERE rank BETWEEN 1 AND 2`

Comment: I've given up answering questions concerning PHP's deprecated API

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
  $getCredits = mysql_query("SELECT `look`,`username`,`activity_points` FROM `users` WHERE `rank` = '1' OR `rank` = '2' ORDER BY `activity_points` DESC LIMIT 10");
```

Using the SQL OR Operator

[more about SQL Operators](http://www.w3schools.com/Sql/sql_and_or.asp)

Answer (score 0):

You can also use this: 
I have used "rank IN ('1','2')" instead of "rank = '0'" so it get all data with rank 1 and 2. You can add more number in bracket then it will get all data having those rank in the bracket from the table.

```
$getCredits = mysql_query("SELECT `look`,`username`,`activity_points` FROM `users` WHERE `rank` IN ('1','2')  ORDER BY `activity_points` DESC LIMIT 10");
```

Comment: His problem is to select both 1 and 2 rank. So it fulfill the query? Why you think it is wrong?